# Android app doesn't show in Market.Compatibility issue

Tags: android, compatibility, google-play

I can't see my application on Android Market. If i try to check it in android market online, using my pc, i'm able to find my application but if i try to download a popup tell me that the app is not compatible with my devices. I have a Samsung Galaxy S2 (i9100) and Huawei Ideos U8150. Both are present in the compatibility table in android-market-publish.

I did so many changes to android manifest.xml without positive result. I tried to change the screen options, sdk version options exc.

Application was build using Sdk version 10 (2.3).

This is my android manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="mypackage"
android:versionCode="7"
android:versionName="1.1" >
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:smallScreens="true"   android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true"/>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="10"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/pulsantegrande"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <service android:name="mypackage.ForegroundService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="mypackage.ForegroundService" />

        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <activity
        android:name="mypackage.Main"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name="mypackage.BootReceiver" android:enabled="true" >
 <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
</application>

</manifest>
```

**UPDATE:**
To fix problem go into your android-market-publish==>product details. In publish option tab YOU MUST DEACTIVATE stuff protection. (to protect your application you should use licensing system) ...et voilá your application is finally show on android market.