# Application compatibility with Android 2.3.6

Tags: android, filter, compatibility, google-play

Could anybody explain why application **compatible with Samsung Galaxy II 2.3.5** (and available on Market for this device) is **not compatible with Samsung Galaxy II 2.3.6** (not available at Market).

App runs on SGSII 2.3.6. when device is connected via cable with pc/eclipce without problem.

Why Market filters this app out for SGSII 2.3.6 ?

Thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="package.name" android:versionCode="23" android:versionName="2.3">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="5" android:targetSdkVersion="10" android:maxSdkVersion="13"/> 

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_APN_SETTINGS"></uses-permission>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"></uses-permission> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: app with manifest added above

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `android:maxSdkVersion="13"`

Comment: I do not want to make this app available for ICS

Comment: If this solves your problem, it is an issue with version. If it doesn't, there probably is something else with that particular phone.

Comment: Few users complain that app is not avilable for their devices after upgrade from 2.3.x to 2.3.6. So I would not say that it is a problem with particular device. On the other hand I could try whether removing android:maxSdkVersion="13" help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have "Copy Protection" enabled or disabled in the Android Developer Console for your application?  I don't know when it was deprecated but it may be as simple as turning that off.  This is really just a shot in the dark.

I've read that sometimes there have been issues with that affecting device compatibility but I don't have any further explanation of why.  (See also this question: [Android app doesn't show in Market.Compatibility issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9337109))

[image: Copy Protection Off]

A little more information...  on the page about the [Market Filters](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/market-filters.html) there is a line that says

> Google Play will not show copy-protected applications on developer
>   devices or unreleased devices.

Perhaps the specific device hardware isn't yet listed as a "released" device?     Not sure if this could be it or not.  Is there a hardware model number for each device you could post? (for both the 2.3.5 and 2.3.6 devices, or is it the same device just before and after you upgraded?)

Additional information about how the [Copy Protection could be cause of app not showing up](http://www.1908media.com/2009/11/is-android-copy-protection-a-blessing-or-curse/).

Comment: I guess Copy protection shold not have nothink to do with device compatibility or Market filtering. Thanks for this link, I will try to switch it Off and be back to you.

Comment: Use the upvote and checkmark if this answer solves your problem. Thanks! I hope this helps.

Comment: I can try it but as well still want to finaly have Copy protection flag set On...

Comment: I'm pretty sure the copy protection doesn't help if somebody has rooted their phone, so in a way it's a bit of a false sense of safety.  The new licensing service mechanism is linked from that page (I haven't used it yet). http://developer.android.com/guide/market/licensing/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Check the Supported Devices section in the Publishing Options section in the Android Developer Console.  It lists the required features and has a link "Show devices" which lists the devices your application is compatible with (which is fascinating in any case).

[image]

Comment: Supported Devices section shows devices only not Device+Android version, SGSII is supported. Only combination SGSII + Android 2.3.6 is somehow not supported.

Comment: On the phone(s) if you go into `Settings` --> `About phone` what does it list for `Model number` for each phone?

Comment: What "Screen layouts" is your device compatible with?  SGS2 is an xlarge from what I've read.  Maybe there was a tweak to the DPI between 2.3.5 and 2.3.6.  Another long shot: press the "Clear Data" button on the phone in `Settings` -> `Manage Applications` -> `Google Play Store`

Comment: Parametrs both are same: scale is 1,5; DPI is 240; pixels 800x480

Comment: Screen layouts: SMALL NORMAL LARGE XLARGE 
Required device features: android.hardware.touchscreen